# Using Rails, not sure if I should use belongs_to or not

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, belongs-to

Very new to Rails... I'm building out functionality that lets people compare photos, and I can't decide exactly how I should structure it.  Ideally what I'd like is to have a "comparisons" table which keeps a record of the IDs of the photos compared as well as the user that compared them, but I'm not quite sure whether this warrants use of the "belongs_to" function or not.  If so, how do I specify that each comparison belongs to TWO separate photos?

Answer (score 1):

The following `has_many, :through => Model` structure will let you have additonal properties on the join table, e.g. 'comparing_user_id'.

```
class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :appearances
  has_many :users, :through => :appearances
end

class Appearance < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :photo
  belongs_to :user
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :appearances
  has_many :photos, :through => :appearances
end
```

Comment: Seemed like appearance was a more appropiate and descriptive name than comparison.  Naming is important.

Comment: I think you didn't get the question. It's named a comparison because it's a model containing *two* photos and also a user.

Comment: @JakubHampl That's correct, though I think using the :through parameter may still be the key to making this work.  I'm going to play around with it and see what I get....

Comment: @StephenCorwin What `:through` lets you do is to access a collection of all photos related to a particular photo via the join model. So in your case this will allow you to access from a particular instance of Photo all the photos that a comparison was made with that photo.